# Find $n$ if the quotient group $\Bbb Z_{40}/\langle \overline{15} \rangle $ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If the quotient group $\Bbb Z_{40}/⟨\overline{15}⟩$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n$ then find $n$. But, I'm just got confused about the equivalence classes.

My question is about this symbol $\overline {15}$. What does that mean by $\overline {15}$ exactly? And, what is a different meaning between $\langle 15\rangle $ and $\langle \overline {15}\rangle $?

Comment: @Bob Did you mean that $\bar{15}$ is <15>?

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\overline{15}=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:40|n-15\}$. $\langle 15\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $15$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ while $\langle\overline{15}\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $\overline{15}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$.

Now, note that $\overline{15}$ has ordere $8$. Therefore, by the [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{40}}{\langle\overline{15}\rangle}$ has order $5$ and, since the unique group of order $5$ is $\mathbb{Z}_5$, it follows that $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{40}}{\langle\overline{15}\rangle}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{5}$$ and $n=5$.

Answer (score 1):

$\langle \overline {15}\rangle $ is defined to be the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{40}$ containing $\overline {15}$.

Check that $\langle \overline {15}\rangle =\{\overline 0,\overline {15},\overline {30},\overline{5},\overline {20},\overline{35},\overline {10},\overline {25}\}$.

Now $|\Bbb Z_{40}||\langle \overline {15}\rangle |=|\Bbb Z_n|\implies n=\dfrac{40}{8}=5$